# Applescript run terminal commands one by one?

Tags: bash, command, applescript, backup, vps

I want to use AppleScript to do the following:

1. SSH to remote server, and zip a folder
2. Download the zipped folder file to local directory

I can already do both 1 and 2, however the problem is that I don't know how to use AppleScript to do them one after another.

The code currently looks like this:

```
set currentTab to do script("ssh balahbala")
delay 3
do script("pswd") in currentTab
do script("tar -cvzf xxx.tar.gz server_path) in currentTab
set currentTab to do script("scp server:xxx local")
do script ("pswd") in currentTab
```

But I can't do `scp` before the tar running completes, and I also don't want to use delay for `tar`, because if I do that, I have to predict the time that `tar` running...

Is there any way using AppleScript run `scp` just after the `tar`completes?

Comment: Why not just write a `bash` _script_ to to do this!? It would be far more efficient and easier to do, while not having to worry about timing.

Comment: Because if I do "scp xxx local" in server, the file will be downloaded to the server, not my local PC, I have to run that command on my local machine, while the "tar xxx" running on remote...

Comment: You don't need Applescript, just use `bash` like this `tar .. ; scp ...`

Comment: Has anyone recommended you just use `bash` ?  I think you should just use `bash`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need the terminal. Use

```
set yourscript to "command 1;command 2;command 3" 

do shell script quoted form of yourscript
```

Comment: I would omit the `quoted form of`, which will only send the script to the shell as a literal string, which will, of course, be reported as `command not found`.  Simply using `do shell script yourscript` isn't going to go wrong unless the bash script contained within the variable `yourscript` is, itself, not a valid script.

Comment: Corrections aside, while I see the motivation behind this answer, it isn't appropriate for the OP's specific case, given that her script (in its current form) requires an actual terminal to receive user input, which obviously `do shell script` can't provide.  What you could have chosen to advise is a means for her to avoid user interaction by illustrating how a password might be given as part of a particular command (whilst highlighting the security implications of doing this).  Of course, the sensible thing is to show her how to write a bash script.

Answer (score 0):

```
do shell script "say '1';
say '2';
say '3';
"
```

; means do the script of the new line, sorry for my poor English.